# Ошибка при конвертации char в Int

Tags: c#

Должно выводится в консоль, то что вводится пользователем, но выдаёт System.Int32[]
[image: 123]

```
Console.Write("Введите информационную комбинацию: ");
string alpha = Console.ReadLine();
int k = alpha.Length;
char[] strok = new char[k];
for (int i = 0; i < alpha.Length; i++)
{
    strok[i] = alpha[i];
}
int[] word = new int[k];
char[] temp = new char[256];
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    temp[0] = alpha[i];
    word[i] = Convert.ToInt32(temp[0]);
}
Console.WriteLine("Информ.комбинация = " + word);
```

[image: breakpoint]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = string.Join(", ", word);
Console.WriteLine($"*..Message..*{result});
```

Дело в том, что вы обращаетесь ко всему массиву. Вам нужно обращаться к конкретному элементу массива. Либо перебирайте их через foreach и выводите, либо сразу конвертируйте их в одну строку, как я написал в примере выше.

Вариант через foreach:

```
foreach (var word in words)
    Console.WriteLine(word);
```

Так же, обратите внимание на то, что переменная с массивом у вас называется "word". Это ведь коллекция, а значит "wordS"

UPD:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скопировал ваш код. Смотрим в то, что находится у нас в данном массиве. Давайте чуть подправим ваш код:

```
Console.Write("Введите информационную комбинацию: ");
var combs = Console.ReadLine();
var infCombs = combs.Remove(0, combs.IndexOf("1"));
Console.WriteLine($"Строка - {combs}. Её длина: {combs.Length}");
Console.WriteLine($"Информационные разряды - {infCombs}. Её длина - {infCombs.Length}");
```

UPD 2:

```
static string ConvertToString<T>(IEnumerable<T> array) =>
        string.Join(", ", array);

static int[] ConvertToIntArray(string line) =>
        line.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
```

UPD 3:

У вас есть какая-то строка. Допустим, у неё имя line. Нам нужно её конвертировать в массив.

```
int[] result = ConvertToIntArray(line);
```

Допустим, у вас есть массив (у него имя array) и его нужно "красиво" вывести в консоли:

```
string result = ConvertToString(array);
Console.WriteLine(array);
```

Comment: И так, и так выдаёт не 1 0 0 1, а 49 48 48 49

Comment: @ProLink Dfv нужно сами числа в коллекции или их индекс?

Comment: Сами числа нужны.

Comment: Поставьте брейк-поинт и посмотрите, что у вас находится в массиве word. Не думаете ли вы, что у вас в данном массиве находятся некорректные данные?

Comment: Прикрепил выше breakpoint

Comment: @ProLink Обновил ответ. Ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста

Comment: Я реализовывал в массиве, потому что в дальнейшем этот массив будет необходим в операциях с матрицами двоичными.

Comment: @ProLink Добавил 2 метода для конвертации в готовую строку и для конвертации в массив. Объяснить нужно, как использовать или сами разберётесь?

Comment: Лучше объяснить, если вас не затруднит, ибо не совсем понятно как его использовать.

Comment: @ProLink Обновил. Если ответ помог, поставьте, пожалуйста, около него галочку

Comment: Нужно ещё какие-нибудь пояснения?

Comment: Разобрался. Большое спасибо.

Comment: `.ToCharArray()` лишний. Со строки можно `Select` символами брать напрямую.

Comment: Спасибо, подправил

Answer (score 2):

Вы выводите целочисленный массив в консольный метод WriteLine, соответственно, выполняется метод ToString объекта типа System.Int32[], который по умолчанию возвращает название этого типа. Вы можете написать свой метод для вывода массива или просто выполнить WriteLine в цикле для каждого элемента.

Comment: При занесении под цикл WriteLine выдаёт видимо номер бита 49 48 48 49, вместо 1 0 0 1

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, не сам символ, а его код?

Comment: Да. Необходимо, чтобы выводился символ.

Comment: Если да, то к типу char приведите

Answer (score 2):

```
static void Main() {
   Console.Write("Введите информационную комбинацию: ");
   string alpha = Console.ReadLine();
   int k = alpha.Length;
   char[] strok = new char[k];
   for (int i = 0; i < alpha.Length; i++)
   {
       strok[i] = alpha[i];
   }
   int[] word = new int[k];
   char[] temp = new char[256];
   for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
   {
       temp[0] = alpha[i];
       word[i] = Convert.ToInt32(temp[0]);
   }
   Console.WriteLine("Информ.комбинация = ");
   foreach (var w in word)
       Console.Write((char)w);
}
```